# Is initializing char array from string literal considered to be a implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, declaration, implicit-conversion

Is
`char x[10] = "banana";`
considered to be a implicit conversion from `const char[7]` to `char[10]`?

Since `std::is_convertible<const char[7], char[10]>::value` evaluates to `false` the obvious answer would be that it isn't, but I couldn't find a proper definition of implicit conversion anywhere. Reading [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) I'd say that it is because:

> Implicit conversions are performed whenever an expression of some type
> T1 is used in context that does not accept that type, but accepts some
> other type T2; in particular: ... when initializing a new object of
> type T2, including return statement in a function returning T2;

although I'm not sure why they didn't exclude explicit constructors from this case.

Follow-up question (which may be useless):

Are arrays completely excluded from any kind of conversions (meaning array-to-array conversions) ?

Comment: _Are arrays completely excluded from any kind of conversions ?_ You really haven't heard of array-to-pointer conversion?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer I meant array to array conversion. I will edit my question.

Comment: This is Aggregate initialization see __Character arrays__ here - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization  No conversion(s) happening.

Comment: @RichardCritten _This is Aggregate initialization_ Are you sure that cppreference is correct calling it aggregate initialization?

Comment: `char x[10] = {'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', '\0' };` with the remaining 3 being implicitly initialized to `'\0'`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer the 1st example (in Character arrays) says the 2 initialisations are equivalent and cppreference knows more than me :)

Comment: Follow up -  Declaration and Initialisation of __Character arrays__ gets it's own section in the Standard [dcl.init.string](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.string)

Comment: @RichardCritten exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Language-lawyerly speaking, initializing char array from string literal is a implicit conversion.

[[conv.general]](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.general#3):

> An expression *`E`* can be *implicitly converted* to a type `T` if and only if the declaration `T t=E;` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` ([dcl.init]).

Note that the core language only defines implicit conversion from an expression to a type. So the meaning of "implicit conversion from `const char[7]` to `char[10]`" is undefined.

`is_convertible<From, To>::value` is `false` whenever `To` is an array type, because it is defined to produce `false` if `To` is not a valid return type, which an array is not. (This can be implemented in different ways.)

[[meta.rel]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.rel#5):

> The predicate condition for a template specialization `is_­convertible<From, To>` shall be satisfied if and only if the return expression in the following code would be well-formed, including any implicit conversions to the return type of the function:
>
> ```
> To test() {
>   return declval<From>();
> }
> ```

Arrays can rarely be the destination of implicit conversions, since they can be neither parameter types nor return types. But they are not excluded from [temporary materialization conversion](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.rval).

Comment: "_initializing char array from string literal is a implicit conversion_" - That doesn't feel right. The character array can be written like `char x[10] = {'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', '\0' };` or `char x[10] = "banana";` and they both result in aggregate (array) initialization. I don't see the conversion.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I said "language-lawyerly". It doesn't matter in practice.

Comment: I meant it in a "language-lawyerly" kind of way too :-) String literals just provide an additional way of initializing character arrays.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The standard defines implicit conversion in terms of (copy-)initialization. So according to the standard, even the weirdest initialization is a implicit conversion. Though it's probably not intuitive or meaningful in practice.

Comment: One never knows when that knowledge may come in handy. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

In this declaration

```
char x[10] = "banana";
```

there is no conversion. Elements of the string literal are used to initialize elements of the array. In fact it is equivalent to

```
char x[10] = { 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', '\0' };
```

If instead of the array you declared a pointer like

```
const char *x = "banana";
```

then the string literal having the type `const char[7]` would be implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `const char *`.

The above declaration is equivalent to

```
const char *x = &"banana"[0];
```

Comment: For clarity, I think your first sentence should end "there is no conversion" or perhaps "there is neither implicit nor explicit conversion"

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a copy of the newest standard, but in [dcl.init.string], there is the paragraph:

> If there are fewer initializers than there are array elements, each element not explicitly initialized shall be zero-initialized (8.5).
> <sub>C++.2011§8.5.2¶3</sub>

So it is the specified behavior for initializing a `char` array of known size with a literal.

Comment: Sorry, but does this answer my question ? I can't find the connection.

Comment: Your first question. And it answers it in the negative.

Comment: Arrays are not initialized with assignment, so I am not sure what you want for the answer to your followup.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you saying it is considered to be a implicit conversion or not ?

Comment: "Not implicit conversion, but initialization specifically described by the standard."

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of overload resolution, it *is* considered to be an implicit conversion, but one that involves no actual conversions (the identity conversion sequence). See [over.ics.list]/4:

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is a character array<sup>125</sup> and the initializer list has a single element that is an
> appropriately-typed *string-literal* (9.4.2), the implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion.
>
> <sup>125</sup> Since there are no parameters of array type, this will only occur as the referenced type of a reference parameter.

The implicit conversion to array type itself (not a reference to array) seems to be pretty restricted: it's apparently only allowed in a variable definition. Something like `static_cast<char[10]>("banana")` won't compile (at least on GCC and Clang).